# How to add check box to a dropdown in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, drop-down-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multi-select dropdown list in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774587/multi-select-dropdown-list-in-asp-net)

I am doing databinding to a dropdown and I want to allow multiple selection using a check box in side the drop down. How can I do that. thanks

Comment: Try https://dropdowncheckboxes.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class CheckBoxDropDownList :
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl,INamingContainer
{
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls ();
        DropDownList ddl=new DropDownList();
        ListItem li=new ListItem("");
        ddl.Items.Add(li);
        ddl.Width =new Unit(100);
        ddl.Attributes.Add("onmousedown", "showdiv()");
        ddl.Attributes.Add("onclick", "showdiv()");
        ddl.Attributes.Add("ondragover", "hidediv()");
        ddl.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "hidediv()");

        CheckBoxList cbl=new CheckBoxList();
        cbl.Width=new Unit(80);

        ListItem li1=new ListItem("ListItem1");
        ListItem li2=new ListItem("ListItem2");
        ListItem li3=new ListItem("ListItem3");

        cbl.Items.Add(li1);
        cbl.Items.Add(li2);
        cbl.Items.Add(li3);

        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div=new 
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
        div.ID="serverdiv";
        div.Controls.Add(cbl);
        div.Style.Add("BORDER-RIGHT", "black 1px solid");
        div.Style.Add("BORDER-TOP", "black 1px solid");
        div.Style.Add("BORDER-LEFT", "black 1px solid");
        div.Style.Add("BORDER-BOTTOM", "black 1px solid");
        div.Style.Add("VISIBILITY", "hidden");

        this.Controls.Add(ddl);
        this.Controls.Add(div);
    }
}
```

Comment: SShebly : If you posting someone elses answer, it will be better if you can reference the original answer. I found the same answer here. http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/42/211693.aspx  Please don't just copy and paste someone elses answer :)

Answer (score 1):

A combo box is used to select one of many items, not many of many. This is why why it does not have a SelectedItems Property. Depending on your interface (example WPF) you could use  a Data Binding Item Template. But I would strongly advise not to do this, it is bad practise and you are also hiding the multiple items the user has selected.

It you want to allow a user to select multiple items use a ListBox or ListView so the users can see what selections they have made

Answer (score 1):

Please read these article about [Multiselect Dropdown in Asp.net 4.0 using C#](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1591-multiselect-dropdownlist-in-aspnet-using-csharp-40-.aspx) and [multi-select dropdownlist with checkboxes](http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/42/211693.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

here is good example for [multiple selection in dropdown list using check boxes](http://dblendea.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/multiselect-dropdownlist/)

I hope it will helps you

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [CheckBoxList control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx)... Isn't it more suited for the multiple selection scenario?