# VS 2005 Webpage. Multi select dropdown list in asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, listbox, visual-studio-2005

I have a asp.NET webpage written in VS 2005 (C#). It currently contains a dropdown list. I need to change this dropdown list so that multiple items can be selected. Here is the current code (.aspx page)

```
        <div style="float: left; width: 280px;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblExport" EnableViewState="false" runat="server" Text="Export"></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList TabIndex="24" runat="server" Width="70px" ID="ddlExport"
                    DataSource='<%# CodeListManager.Instance().GetCodelist(CodeListCache.Export)%>'
                    DataTextField="Value" DataValueField="Name" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Export") %>'
                    AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                    <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
```

Is there a way to keep this as a dropdown or would I need to use a listbox? If I use a listbox how would I program it to allow multi select? Can this be done on .aspx page or will it have to be on the aspx.cs page?

Comment: please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774587/multi-select-dropdown-list-in-asp-net

Comment: I did see that...but is there a way to do it without javascript? Thanks.