# populating a multiselect dropdown with selected values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my controller I am returning a list that contains multiple items:

**SelectedList:**

- Apple
- Orange
- Pear

I also have a full list that I am returning as well:

**FullList:**

- Apple
- Cranberry
- Cherry
- Orange
- Grape
- Peach
- Plum
- Pear

I would like to have a multi-select dropdown list that has the items in the SelectedList selected.

Currently I have this (which was setup for a single select dropdown:

```
var fruitDictionary = (from fl in Model.Fruits select new { Value = fl.FruitID, Text = fl.FruitName});

var fruitSelectList = new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)fruitDictionary, "Value", "Text");

@Html.ListBoxFor(fl=>fl.Fruits, fruitSelectList);
```

How would I select the items in the dropdown from my selectedList?  I'm missing something to combine the 2 lists somehow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774587/multi-select-dropdown-list-in-asp-net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Fruits, Model.FrSelectList)
```

or

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Fruits, new MultiSelectList
         (Model.FrSelectList,"Value","Text"), new { multiple = "multiple" })
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that states: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items

Comment: The error is from client side or server side? I updated my answer, take a look at it.