# DropDownListFor In Edit Mode

Tags: c#, jquery

i have a drop down list. I am selecting multiple options and saving 
it but in edit mode, i want the selected item to be selected back in 
list of item in drop down list in Mvc using razor

// here i am uploading document by selecting users

```
   <fieldset>
        <legend>DocShared</legend>



        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="file">Please select File To Upload</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="file" name="ChooseFile" />
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <label>Please select Single/Muliple Users</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="text" name="Description" />
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <label>Description</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">

            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Users, Model.AllEmployess, new { @id = "multiple", @class = "chosen", @multiple = "multiple", style = "width: 350px;"  })
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save&Upload" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
```

// now in the edit i am getting a list but  i want the dropdownlist selected item (In the same view)

Comment: Explain in more detail!!

Comment: Given you're mentioning DropDownListFor, am I right to assume that this is in an MVC View?

Comment: Saving it but in edit mode? I want the selected item to be selected in list of item -- do you mean on next load of page do you want to mark previous set of selection as selected?

Comment: Yes on the next load of the view i want the selected values to be highlighted . i am getting the saved values in the form of list

Comment: Check this link to get a clue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774587/multi-select-dropdown-list-in-asp-net. And for MVC, perhaps some MVC guy can help.

Comment: but in the above link its said  just the how to save it and get into other list. But we need the edit of dropdown list where the item should be selected