# How to add Checkbox inside the Gridview dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I need to do add Checkbox inside the Gridview dropdownlist, the dropdown list was added in RowDataBound event and it has fetch the data from database.

```
 protected void grdupload_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {           
        List<string> coll = new List<string>();
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string fnCriteria = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["fnCriteria"].ToString();               
            DropDownList ddlfnCriteria = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlfnCriteria") as DropDownList);
            coll.Add(fnCriteria);
            ddlfnCriteria.DataSource = coll.ToList();
            ddlfnCriteria.Text = fnCriteria;
            ddlfnCriteria.DataBind();                

        }
    }
```

Please suggest me to get a solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use checkbox list instead?

Comment: Though the code you posted and question you asked are not seem to be connected. Anyway did you try find and use any third party jQuery/Asp.Net dropdown plugin that is designed to show checkboxes in dropdown items?

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774587/multi-select-dropdown-list-in-asp-net

Comment: The Code shows how the dropdownlist is bind and am asking how to add checkbox with in it

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these links.

1) http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource55-Checkbox-list-in-Dropdown-using-Aspnet-Ajax-PopupControlExtender-control.aspx

2) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66572/A-Multiple-Selection-DropDownList-a-CheckBoxList-I

3) http://www.dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=63