# Store in a variable the SelectedValue of a DropDownList then call it

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am adding a user to a role in asp.net but i want to get the selected role from a dropdownlist.  a single option is working for me but i need to implement a two choices dropD list.

```
public partial class Register : Page
{
    protected void Selection_Change(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var tr = TakeRole.SelectedValue; // store it in some variable
    }
    protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
       // code 
       if (result.Succeeded)
        {
           manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "SomeRoleName");
    }
}
```

on aspx i have

```
        <asp:DropDownList id="TakeRole" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Selection_Change" runat="server">
          <asp:ListItem> Supplier </asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Selected="True"> Customer </asp:ListItem>
       </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: i think you are looking for this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774587/multi-select-dropdown-list-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Please use a listbox on multi selection mode and restrict selection to 2 items. Else you can use dropdownlist with jQuery. 
If you intend to use checkboxlist, then other than binding source, in check changed event count checked  items to 2 and if more items are selected an alert is to be displayed.

Comment: the scope where the variable is, that is the problem i'm having that i need to use it inside the if statement. like i said the literal string is working but i need to call the var that has the store info. thanks