# How to allow checkbox="true" for asp dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to allow checkbox="true" for asp dropdownlist

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide the relevant code you have already?

Comment: Please add more content in you post and mention what actual problem you are facing. Better sharing some mark-up and code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-select dropdown list in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774587/multi-select-dropdown-list-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [telerik component](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/checkboxes/defaultvb.aspx?show-source=true) as like the following:

```
  <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server" CheckBoxes="true" EnableCheckAllItemsCheckBox="true"
                    Width="250" Label="Select book genres:">
                    <Items>
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Arts" />
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Biographies" />
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Children's Books" />
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Computers &amp; Internet" />
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Cooking" />
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="History" />
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Fiction" />
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Mystery" />
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Nonfiction" />
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Romance" />
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Science Fiction" />
                        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Travel" />
                 </Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

or else you can use [Converting ASP.NET Control Check Box List into Drop-Down Check Box List](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132359/Converting-ASP-NET-Control-Check-Box-List-into-Dro)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) for this

you need to keep  `multiple="multiple"` for **HTML**  like this

```
<div class="mid-width wrapItems">
    <select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="buckHunter">
        <option value="1">Large Antelope</option>
        <option value="2">Large Antelope </option>
        <option value="3">Medium to Large Antelope </option>
        <option value="4">Small Game to Medium Game </option>
        <option value="5">N/A</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Multiselect activating using **Jquery** can be done like this :

```
$('.multiselect').multiselect({ 
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
    maxHeight: 200,
});
```

So I have made this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/phnv1hvd/) in Fiddle you can check out this so that you can able to check multiple in dropdown

Answer (score 0):

to allow `checkbox="true"` for asp dropdownlist you can try `asp:DropDownCheckBoxes` tag.

```
<asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="mydropdown0" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" UseButtons="true"></asp:DropDownCheckBoxes>
```